# What does the exist_ok parameter do in the pathlib.Path module?

Tags: python-3.x

The official documentation is extremely cryptic to a layman:

```
 def mkdir(self, mode=0o777, parents=False, exist_ok=False):
        """
        Create a new directory at this given path.
        """
        if self._closed:
            self._raise_closed()
        try:
            self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            if not parents or self.parent == self:
                raise
            self.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            self.mkdir(mode, parents=False, exist_ok=exist_ok)
        except OSError:
            # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system
            # could give priority to other errors like EACCES or EROFS
            if not exist_ok or not self.is_dir():
                raise
```

Usually people use `exist_ok = True` but I have no idea why.

Comment: If the path already exists, `FileExistsError` is raised, but if you don't care (this is often the case) you can use the `exist_ok = True` and the exception won't be raised

Answer (score 0):

ofirule's comment basically answered it. exist_ok = True tells it to not throw an exception if the dir you're are trying to create already exists. This is a useful if you just want to make sure the dir exists and create it if it doesn't. I use this a lot for temp subdirs. Before I write to them I make sure they exist. Saves me from having to code it as an 'if not exists then create' if statement.